# Showing a surface of revolution is a submanifold by means of the rank theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

I'm trying to show the set $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{b^2-\frac{b^2}{a^2}t^2}\cos\varphi\\\sqrt{b^2-\frac{b^2}{a^2}t^2}\sin\varphi\\t\end{pmatrix}:t\in(-a,a),\varphi\in[0,2\pi)\right\}$$
is a $2$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$. This is clearly a surface of revolution and normally I would show that it can be parametrised by an immersive embedding, but I don't have these concepts available to me for this exercise. That is, I have to either directly show this set is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$ or use the rank theorem (given a function $f$, if at every point of the preimage $f^{-1}(c)$ the differential of $f$ has full rank, $f^{-1}(c)$ is a submanifold of appropriate dimension).

The former is not a particularly attractive idea, while the problem with the latter is that I'm having trouble coming up with a suitable $f$ to use. Any suggestions in this regard?

Comment: So you want to write your set in terms of $x, y, z$. Try to get rid of $\varphi$  first, then $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll try doing this now.